# Finding the range of $f(x) = 5-x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $a < b$ and $f: (a, b] \to R$, $f(x) = 5 - x$.

What is the range of the function?
How do you find the range of an equation with unknowns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work through step-by-step:

1. $x$ has the range $(a,b]$.
2. $-x$ has the range $[-b,-a)$.
3. $5+(-x)$ has the range $[5-b,5-a)$.